# Sending live update notifications for website

Tags: android, ios, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, live-update

This might be a bit of a raw question (as in I haven't got much to work with), but here it is anyways:

I have a website with news added regularly. I would like to create an app that notifies the user when a news story is added. Any idea how this can be achieved? I don't have much server side programming experience.

I did a bit of searching around and found GCM for android and read through the setup process but it seems more for individual notifications rather than live updates because you need to use a registration ID and can only send to 1000 at once (I will have over 50,000 users day one)(Also, what happens if two devices have the same registration ID?). It is also somewhat complicated to understand, especially setting up the server side of it. I also found APN for iOS but it also seems similar and way too complicated to set up. I would love for someone to point me in the right direction.

Or a way to give live RSS updates will do as well because I have RSS set up.

I could check the RSS for any modifications at a set time interval but I want to avoid downloading the RSS feed repeatedly. (I will have to do that if nothing else works...)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at services like Parse.com

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks a lot, that is pretty much what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some links that can help you out!!

http://kyleroderick.com/writing/live-stream-notifications/

http://www.airbop.com/

http://www.theverge.com/2015/3/26/8293353/periscope-live-streaming-twitter-meerkat

https://parse.com/

Comment: The comment by Paulw11 is more what I was looking for, even though these links were helpful. That was the correct answer. If you add that to your answer I will be sure to accept.